# Find function pointer SBType in LLDB when DWARF info contains only typedef

Tags: c++, lldb

Is it possible to find a function pointer SBType using something like `lldb.target.FindTypes()` without iterating over all types in all modules, given that the DWARF information seems to contain only the typedef to the type?

So in my C++ code I have:

```
typedef struct _object {
  PyObject_HEAD
} PyObject;
typedef void (*PythonToCppFunc)(PyObject*,void*);
```

When I execute

```
script print lldb.target.FindFirstType("PythonToCppFunc").GetName()
script print lldb.target.FindFirstType("PythonToCppFunc").GetCanonicalType()
script print lldb.target.FindFirstType("PythonToCppFunc").GetCanonicalType().GetName()
```

I get

```
PythonToCppFunc
void (*)(struct _object *, void *)
void (*)(_object *, void *)
```

But when I try to look for the canonical type or its name

```
script print lldb.target.FindTypes("void (*)(struct _object *, void *)").GetSize()
```

I get 0 results. I also tried variations of the above with different whitespace, without `struct` keyword, etc. without any results.

The best I could find is to iterate over all module types and compare the names, so something like this actually works, but is very slow:

```
target.GetModuleAtIndex(i).GetTypes().GetTypeAtIndex(j).GetName() == "void (*)(_object *, void *)"
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug, or is it not supported?

Comment: How would you iterate over all types in all modules? I've not found any API to do it.

Comment: @random You use SBTarget::GetNumModules() to get the number of modules, then you iterate using SBTarget::GetModuleAtIndex(i), for each module you call SBModule::GetTypes(), then you call SBTypeList::GetTypeAtIndex() to get the actual type.

Comment: Thanks! for some reason I did not noticed that call.